# Stopping a Function After It Has Fulfilled a Requirement

Tags: javascript, html, dom, settimeout, onload

That is the best way I could describe it. Basically, I have a jpg that I have scrolling across the screen onLoad. I should be able to stop the image, and make it hidden after it has made 3 descending passes across the screen. I have been at it for a couple hours now, but can't figure out how to make it work without the use of an onClick button. I need it to stop on its own. Here is the script:

```
    function moveit()
    {
    dom=document.getElementById("roman").style;


    dom.top= parseInt(dom.top)+tinc+"px"; 
    dom.left= startleft+"px";


    dom.visibility= "visible";
    startleft=startleft+linc;

    if (startleft<= 20)     
    {linc=linc*-1;      
    window.document.roman.src="roman.jpg"; }

    if (startleft>= window.screen.width-10) 
    {linc=linc*-1;
    window.document.roman.src="roman.jpg"; }


    to=setTimeout("moveit();", 100) ;
    }
```

And the body looks like this:

```
    <body onload="moveit()">
    <div id="roman" style="position:absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden;">
    <img name="roman" src="roman.jpg"/>
    </div>

    <form>
    <div id="button" style="position:absolute; top: 315px; left: 10px;">
    <input type="button" value="stop" onClick="clearTimeout(to)">
    </div>
    </form>
```

I have tried several ways, but have not been able to remove the button aspect. I would like the image to makes 3 full passes from right to left, stop, and then become hidden. Any thoughts oh how to do it without the button?

Comment: The string in setTimeout serves no purpose other than to slow down your code slightly. `setTimeout("moveit();", 100);` should be `setTimeout(moveit, 100);`.

Comment: Thank you, I took that part out :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a counter variable to keep track of how many times your image bounces horizontally. Once that counter reaches a certain number, don't reset the timeout:

```
var passes = 0;

var imageStyle = document.getElementById("roman").style;
imageStyle.visibility = "visible"; 

// Referring to the image with document.roman isn't recommended; give it an ID
// and use getElementById instead.
window.document.roman.src = "roman.jpg";

function moveit() {
    imageStyle.top = parseInt(dom.top) + tinc + "px"; 
    imageStyle.left = startleft + "px";

    startleft = startleft + linc;

    if (startleft <= 20 || startleft >= window.screen.width - 10) {
        linc = linc * -1;
        passes++;
    }

    if (passes < 3) {
        to = setTimeout(moveit, 100);
    }
}
```

Notice that I removed some redundant code. You don't have to set the visibility or image source every time the timer fires. Just do it at the beginning.

Comment: My teacher wrote the original code above lol, I didn't think it could possibly be right. I'm disappointed that I have been paying money for him to teach me, as his code rarely works when used in assignments >.<

Comment: Thank you for making those changes, I really appreciate it :)
Do I still need to keep the image in the body? Or can I remove the corresponding body portion of my code?